Azure - Eternal Orchestration
I'm trying to create an eternal orchestrator, but I can't seem to get it working.
Here is a snippet of my code.
HTTP Trigger
@FunctionName("MQMessageOrchestrate")
    public HttpResponseMessage mqMessageOrchestrate(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = { HttpMethod.GET,
                    HttpMethod.POST }, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            @DurableClientInput(name = "durableContext") DurableClientContext durableContext,
            final ExecutionContext context) {

        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

        // Initialize durable task client
        DurableTaskClient client = durableContext.getClient();

        // Start orchestration
        String instanceId = client.scheduleNewOrchestrationInstance("TestOrchestrator");

        // Output instance id
        context.getLogger().info("Created new Java orchestration with instance ID = " + instanceId);

        // Return status of orchestration in response
        return durableContext.createCheckStatusResponse(request, instanceId);
    }

Orchestrator
@FunctionName("TestOrchestrator")
    public void testOrchestrator(
            @DurableOrchestrationTrigger(name = "ctx") TaskOrchestrationContext ctx, ExecutionContext context) {

        System.out.println("Processing stuff...");

        ctx.createTimer(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).await();

        ctx.continueAsNew(null);

    }

Expectation
I was expecting that the orchestrator would repeat, I have seen similar code that don't produce the same error but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.
[2024-12-05T01:54:00.002Z] Created new Java orchestration with instance ID = d14eec3b-aad1-4508-92df-32d883201a40
[2024-12-05T01:54:00.011Z] Function "MQMessageOrchestrate" (Id: c125b1d3-35d7-428f-a831-1afe7903eeae) invoked by Java Worker
[2024-12-05T01:54:00.036Z] Executing 'Functions.TestOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=a087455b-a3ff-4b41-904f-c468d693d7dd)
[2024-12-05T01:54:00.042Z] Executed 'Functions.MQMessageOrchestrate' (Succeeded, Id=c125b1d3-35d7-428f-a831-1afe7903eeae, Duration=833ms)
[2024-12-05T01:54:00.064Z] Processing stuff...
[2024-12-05T01:54:00.078Z] Function "TestOrchestrator" (Id: a087455b-a3ff-4b41-904f-c468d693d7dd) invoked by Java Worker
[2024-12-05T01:54:00.085Z] Executed 'Functions.TestOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=a087455b-a3ff-4b41-904f-c468d693d7dd, Duration=57ms)
[2024-12-05T01:54:06.686Z] Executing 'Functions.TestOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=b8aff574-c31f-4e7a-8269-571d303ec402)
[2024-12-05T01:54:06.693Z] Processing stuff...
[2024-12-05T01:54:00.078Z] Function "TestOrchestrator" (Id: a087455b-a3ff-4b41-904f-c468d693d7dd) invoked by Java Worker
[2024-12-05T01:54:00.085Z] Executed 'Functions.TestOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=a087455b-a3ff-4b41-904f-c468d693d7dd, Duration=57ms)
[2024-12-05T01:54:06.686Z] Executing 'Functions.TestOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=b8aff574-c31f-4e7a-8269-571d303ec402)
[2024-12-05T01:54:06.693Z] Processing stuff...

Reality
But this is what happened after the first orchestration. The error says the orchestrator has already completed.
[2024-12-05T01:54:06.693Z] Processing stuff...
[2024-12-05T01:54:06.714Z] Executed 'Functions.TestOrchestrator' (Failed, Id=b8aff574-c31f-4e7a-8269-571d303ec402, Duration=27ms)
[2024-12-05T01:54:06.715Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.TestOrchestrator. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: IllegalStateException: The orchestrator has already completed
Stack: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The orchestrator has already completed

EDIT
I finally figured it out. It's not as intuitive as you would expect but  here is the updated code. This works as expected but I don't understand why. The timer needs to be executed after continueAsNew.
Orchestrator
@FunctionName("TestOrchestrator")
    public void testOrchestrator(
            @DurableOrchestrationTrigger(name = "ctx") TaskOrchestrationContext ctx, ExecutionContext context) {

        ctx.callActivity("DoCleanup", "test").await();

        // Log orchestration continued
        context.getLogger().info("Orchestration restarted as new ...");

        // Continue as new to restart the orchestration
        ctx.continueAsNew(null);

        // Pause for a specified duration before the next iteration
        ctx.createTimer(Duration.ofSeconds(0)).await();

    }


Can you provide your GitHub repo?

@DasariKamali Thank you for your response. I created a temporary repo for this case as the project I am working on is company sensitive. Here is the repo.
https://github.com/losinigo/sample-code.git

To avoid the error, I have added the below code to the MQOrchestrator.

I have added scheduleNewOrchestrationInstance in the code below to successfully start a new orchestration.

        try {
            System.out.println("Processing stuff...");
            Duration delay = Duration.ofSeconds(5);
            ctx.createTimer(delay);
            DurableTaskClient client = durableContext.getClient();
            String newInstanceId = client.scheduleNewOrchestrationInstance("TestOrchestrator");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            context.getLogger().severe("Error occurred during orchestration: " + e.getMessage());
        }

Here, is the complete code
MQOrchestrator.java :
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.time.Duration;

import com.microsoft.durabletask.*;
import com.microsoft.durabletask.azurefunctions.DurableClientContext;
import com.microsoft.durabletask.azurefunctions.DurableClientInput;
import com.microsoft.durabletask.azurefunctions.DurableOrchestrationTrigger;

public class MQOrchestrator {

    @FunctionName("MQMessageOrchestrate")
    public HttpResponseMessage mqMessageOrchestrate(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = { HttpMethod.GET,
                    HttpMethod.POST }, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            @DurableClientInput(name = "durableContext") DurableClientContext durableContext,
            final ExecutionContext context) {

        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");
        DurableTaskClient client = durableContext.getClient();
        String instanceId = client.scheduleNewOrchestrationInstance("TestOrchestrator");
        context.getLogger().info("Created new Java orchestration with instance ID = " + instanceId);
        return durableContext.createCheckStatusResponse(request, instanceId);
    }

    @FunctionName("TestOrchestrator")
    public void testOrchestrator(
            @DurableOrchestrationTrigger(name = "ctx") TaskOrchestrationContext ctx,
            @DurableClientInput(name = "durableContext") DurableClientContext durableContext,
            ExecutionContext context) {

        try {
            System.out.println("Processing stuff...");
            Duration delay = Duration.ofSeconds(5);
            ctx.createTimer(delay);
            DurableTaskClient client = durableContext.getClient();
            String newInstanceId = client.scheduleNewOrchestrationInstance("TestOrchestrator");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            context.getLogger().severe("Error occurred during orchestration: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

Output :
Now, I can see the repeated orchestration instances running without any issues.

Browser Output :


I don't think this is waiting for the 5 second timer to finish. Based on the logs the instances run within 2 seconds of each other.

I removed the try-catch block in the orchestrator function. I get an error
The orchestrator is blocked and waiting for new inputs. This Throwable should never be caught by user code.
I added await() to ctx.createTimer(delay).await() for the timer to execute and it works as well.
My only concern now is, I am unable to see the status of the succeeding orchestrations and unable to terminate if necessary.

To check the orchestration status and enable termination, use ctx.callActivity() to invoke activities, and leverage DurableTaskClient.getStatus() or DurableTaskClient.terminate() for managing orchestrations.

This seems like a workaround to something that should be working. I appreciate the proposed solution but this won't be suitable to our requirements. I need to make continueAsNew(null) work. I don't understand why even the code provided in their own documentation isn't working. link

I'll review the documentation to understand why continueAsNew(null) isn't working and provide an updated solution
